# Golden Potho stem is yellow however not the leaves

Tags: houseplants

My golden potho has been doing well however recently i have noticed that the stem is turning yellow however the leaves are not yellow.
What could it indicate?

Comment: Can you add a photograph of the plant please?

Comment: Possibly, it has too much fertilizer and not enough light. If the plant is trying to grow fast in low light, it will produce more chlorophyll in the leaves, which will turn them greener. (The basic colour of the plant material is yellow, apart from the chlorophyll). It doesn't need (or like) direct sunlight, but it does need *some* light to keep it yellow.